# How did some users use another font style for username?

Tags: support

This is my profile.

[image]

This is [cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/c%E1%B4%8F%CA%9F%E1%B4%85s%E1%B4%98%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%87%E1%B4%85) Profile.

[image]

If you check the font style of my username and coldspeed username is difference. How can I also display my username as that font style?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's a Unicode

Comment: for example: Latin Letter Small Capital L _Unicode Character “ʟ” (U+029F)_

Comment: Why are people keep asking Unicode questions on Meta?

Comment: @user202729 there is no trace of unicode in the question. Only the comments and answer. Just a simple question about displaying a username, what's wrong with that? Better this than the even more common "why am I downvoted" ones.

Comment: Basically "it's not possible to know what you're asking without getting an answer"? ... ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They didn't. The font style is exactly the same.

They're just using [different characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps).